# Is it possible to add a div to an element horizontally using javascript?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm adding elements to a form in javscript using appendChild, and am wondering if there is a way to append horizontally instead of vertically? Using appendChild(), I tried this:

```
var select_fields = document.createElement('select');
select_fields.setAttribute('id', 'select_fields');
var select_operators = document.createElement('select');
select_operators.setAttribute('id', 'select_operators');
select_operators.setAttribute('display', 'inline')             

var filter_field_header = document.createTextNode('Choose Field:');
filter.appendChild(filter_field_header);
filter.appendChild(select_fields);
filter.appendChild(select_operators);
```

But it still appends vertically. Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us the code related to `filter_field_header` and `select_fields`

Comment: appendChild just appends, you will probably need some styling to get the result you want. Can you make a code snippet with your HTML?

Comment: also it seems like your are incorrectly adding your style. It should be `select_operators.setAttribute("style", "display:inline;");`

Comment: Better yet, `select_operators.style.display = 'inline';`.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I added in the additional lines as requested above , tried all recommendations and it still comes in vertically. I don't have any html just doing this in javascript but perhaps I should

Answer (score -1):

Try using 'float: left' instead of using 'display: inline'